# Facebook and Instagram public data API

Tags: facebook, facebook-graph-api, web-scraping, instagram-api

I want to build a dashboard that enables any company to track the social media activity of its competitors.

For example.. let's say you are a small business owner. You would be able to add the 'facebook/instagram page id's' of your 4-5 competitors within the app. The app would retrieve the historical data of your competitors.. and enable you to interactively explore what they are doing. How often they are posting, at the time of the day, what is liked/not liked, etc.

**Problem is**: Since Cambridge Analytica, Facebook requires app review to allow access to public page data. But how do I show the app.. when I don't have the data to build it?

Does anyone have any remote idea whether the thing that I am trying to build is generally within that would be considered permissible by Facebook?

Comment: _“[…] would be considered permissible by Facebook?”_ - https://developers.facebook.com/docs/apps/review/feature#reference-PAGES_ACCESS lists acceptable uses cases and what you aren’t allowed to do; and the permission reference also does, https://developers.facebook.com/docs/facebook-login/permissions

Answer (score 0):

You can still make your dashboard which will show your Facebook activity.

To get the Facebook page ID of 4-5 competitors. The competitors have to use your app and allow permission to your app for accessing public features.

You have to own a Facebook page. Get OAuth key. For every request to Facebook you will be using this Key. In case of mischievous activity your OAuth key will be blocked.

What you are trying to do is not possible these days and neither permissible by Facebook.

Answer (score 0):

You can build your App already and just use your own Pages for testing - with a Page Token of those Pages. Send Facebook a video how you are using the data in the review process. I have recently got Page Public Content Access approved for that specific use case. Facebook just wants to see how you will use the public content, the App does not need to be 100% finished.

What´s allowed and what´s not allowed: https://developers.facebook.com/docs/apps/review/feature#reference-PAGES_ACCESS

Comment: is there a way to post a comment using Instagram API

Comment: that´s not really the topic here, but: did you check out the api docs? should only take a minute to find out.